# Uwp - Invalid value for registry

Tags: windows, uwp, registry, protocols

I have an uwp app, which is being distributed using  SCCM and every time after a new release is distributed, when a user tries to open the app using the protocol (Eg. Appx:\) an error is displayed by Windows saying "Invalid value for registry" . If the user opens the app  using the ícon on the startup menu, it opens without problem and after that there is no problem openning the app using the protocol anymore.

Anyone have any idea why? And how to solve it ?

The uwp app is built over windows anniversary update.

Thank you

Comment: We cannot say without the means to reproduce the problem. Did you try debugging your app when the problem occurs?

Comment: I changed my text to try to be more clear about the problem. I can't debug the app because  after opening the app for the first time the problem disappears.

Comment: Attach the debugger to the app when the error message appears and check the stacktraces.

Comment: Alternatively, get a trace of what the program accesses on the first and on the subsequent tries with `procmon` and compare them. Probably some version-specific registry key is missing, and the program creates it.

Comment: The important thing is which of _your_ code causes the error.

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teju_shyamsundar/2016/05/30/deploy-an-application-from-windows-store-for-business-via-system-center-configuration-manager/)?

Comment: Our client got this error message when there's no developer license on the client machine (the powershell script also failed with the message: unable to download developerlicense). In our particular case, sideloading of apps was activated but the bundle didn't work. Activating the developer mode and after that reset back to sideloading fixed the issue.

Sorry, only a workaround - but it worked for us.